# Android Java firestore databse curd opartion not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

in my case, I can add different documents and different fields to my data collection in my firestore database. that means add curd operation is working well but I want complete my delete and update function to fulfill my application. my problem is I can't edit/delete my "description" and "title". I have initialized the variable as "DocumentReference" I think the problem is having that. anyone feel free to help me to solve this issue. thank you!
[i have to make EDIT and DELETE functions. but them not working with every documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTQHZ.png)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_AUDIOLIST = "audiolist";

    private EditText editTextTitle;
    private EditText editTextAudiolist;
    private TextView textViewData;

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Category");
    private DocumentReference noteRef = db.document("Category/mindRelax");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
        editTextAudiolist = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_audioList);
        textViewData = findViewById(R.id.text_view_data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        notebookRef.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    return;
                }

                String data = "";

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                    note.setDocumentId(documentSnapshot.getId());

                    String documentId = note.getDocumentId();
                    String title = note.getTitle();
                    String audiolist = note.getAudiolist();

                    data += "ID: " + documentId
                            + "\nTitle: " + title + "\nAudiolist: " + audiolist + "\n\n";
                }

                textViewData.setText(data);
            }
        });
    }

    public void addNote(View v) {
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
        String audiolist = editTextAudiolist.getText().toString();

        Note note = new Note(title, audiolist);

        notebookRef.add(note);
    }

    public void loadNotes(View v) {
        notebookRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        String data = "";

                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                            note.setDocumentId(documentSnapshot.getId());

                            String documentId = note.getDocumentId();
                            String title = note.getTitle();
                            String audiolist = note.getAudiolist();

                            data += "ID: " + documentId
                                    + "\nTitle: " + title + "\nAudiolist: " + audiolist + "\n\n";
                        }

                        textViewData.setText(data);
                    }
                });
    }
    public void updateAudiolist(View v) {
        String audiolist = editTextAudiolist.getText().toString();
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();

        Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();
        note.put( KEY_AUDIOLIST, audiolist);
        note.put( KEY_TITLE, title);

        noteRef.set(note, SetOptions.merge());
        noteRef.update(KEY_TITLE,title, KEY_AUDIOLIST, audiolist);
    }

    public void deleteAudiolist(View v) {
        Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();
        note.put(KEY_AUDIOLIST, FieldValue.delete());

        noteRef.update(note);
        noteRef.update(KEY_AUDIOLIST, FieldValue.delete());
    }

    public void deleteNote(View v) {
        noteRef.delete();
    }
    public void logout (View view){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Can you share any error codes or traces that are returned when you update or delete the note? Otherwise, how is the app not working as it should? You can also check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#java) for ways to update documents using the Android SDK.